# SDK And Jar use with digital persona in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, biometrics

Good day everyone! I'm doing a project in java netbeans this purpose is for finger print scanner. I already have digital persona as my bio metrics. The problem is I want to know where can I find and download SDK and jar files that I can used with my project. If anyone knows please instruct me. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please I need someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to www.crossmatch.com They are the owners of Digital persona which is the manufacturer of digital persona fingerprint reader scanners and their API

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late for you, but I hope to this answer give you help others.
The files you require (SDK & RTE) are in the https://downloads.crossmatch.com/ just select U.are.U SDK for Linux or Windows in category, then you create an account for free and download the zip file. The 3.0 version update supports the following devices – U.are.U 4500 and U.are.U 5xxx readers and modules and the EikonTouch 510 and EikonTouch 710 readers.

Edit: Above don´t work anymore for me on windows 7 64bits, let me suggest this proyect that works great! https://github.com/iamonuwa/Digital-Persona-SDK